# Why does the perf test "Object code reading" fail?

Tags: linux, docker, perf

When I run `perf test`, one test that fails inside a Ubuntu 21.04 Docker container but succeeds on its Ubuntu 21.04 host is `26: Object code reading`. It seems like it could be related to some issues with perf in the container, e.g. `dwarf` unwinding doesn't work at all.

The verbose output is

```
26: Object code reading                                             :
--- start ---
test child forked, pid 92383
maps__set_modules_path_dir: cannot open /lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic dir
Problems setting modules path maps, continuing anyway...
maps__set_modules_path_dir: cannot open /lib/modules/5.11.0-22-generic dir
Problems setting modules path maps, continuing anyway...
Looking at the vmlinux_path (8 entries long)
Failed to open /proc/kcore. Note /proc/kcore requires CAP_SYS_RAWIO capability to access.
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
/proc/{kallsyms,modules} inconsistency while looking for "[bpf]" module!
Using /proc/kallsyms for symbols
Parsing event 'cycles:u'
mmap size 528384B
Reading object code for memory address: 0x7fd8f3dececb
File is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.33.so
On file address is: 0x10decb
test child finished with -1
---- end ----
Object code reading: FAILED!
```

What does the test test for exactly, and why does it fail inside the container? I'm running Docker with `--privileged`.

Comment: What is the exact docket container? Failed code is somewhere around https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11.22/source/tools/perf/tests/code-reading.c#L552 `do_test_code_reading()` https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11.22/source/tools/perf/tests/code-reading.c#L236 `read_object_code()`. Don't know what did fail, but I think docker container may have less files and no some files for kernel image, or there can be some incorrect or incomplete /proc fs inside container. I'm also not sure if `perf test` will be useful to debug dwarf problems.

Comment: It's the standard `ubuntu:hirsute` image.